# Django filters to return HTML that will be rendered in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filters

## my_text

```
my_text = '''The template system works in a two-step process: compiling and rendering. A compiled template is, simply, a list of Node objects.

Thus, to define a custom template tag, you specify how the raw template tag is converted into a Node (the compilation function), and what the node’s render() method does.'''
```

## my_filter

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def format_description(description):
    text = ''
    for i in description.split('\n'):
        text += ('<p class="site-description">' + i + '</p>')
    return text
```

## My problem

I get the output in raw html like so

```
 <p class="site-description">The template system works in a two-step process: compiling and rendering. A compiled template is, simply, a list of Node objects.</p><p class="site-description">    </p><p class="site-description">    Thus, to define a custom template tag, you specify how the raw template tag is converted into a Node (the compilation function), and what the node’s render() method does.</p>
```

instead of

> The template system works in a two-step
>   process: compiling and rendering. A compiled template is, simply, a
>   list of Node objects.
>
> Thus, to define a custom template tag,
>   you specify how the raw template tag is converted into a Node (the
>   compilation function), and what the node’s render() method does.

## The idea

The idea is to get the text and create different paragraph for each part of the list created after the split so the text can be formatted pretty 
and tightty

Comment: Use `mark_safe`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To disable autoescape you can use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) method:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def format_description(description):
    text = ''
    for i in description.split('\n'):
        text += ('<p class="site-description">' + i + '</p>')
    return mark_safe(text)
```

Answer (score 11):

This is explicitly covered in the documentation: [Filters and auto-escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping).

You need to mark the output as safe.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
...
return mark_safe(text)
```